# How to bridge two interfaces with netplan

Tags: networking, network-bridge, router, netplan, gateway

I want to setup a gateway on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with 2 eth ports -
ETH1 - WAN connection, connected to my corporate network with DHCP
ETH0 - LAN connection, connected to my laptop statically

I need to use netplan.

Please assist with sample configuration. thank you!

Comment: does [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html.en-CA#bridging) help?

Comment: Thanks Doug. I am just not sure how to route my LAN traffic thru my WAN interface. What are the routing rules and iptables, and how do I configure it using netplan? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know that any special routing rules are required, I don't have any. A simple router iptables rules set (no firewall stuff) example is [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2310269&p=13425557#post13425557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://netplan.io/examples

## Sample of two interfaces :

```
            ethernets:
            eth0:
            addresses:
                - 192.168.2.2/24
            routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 192.168.2.1
                metric: 100
                table: 101
            routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.2.0/24
                table: 101
            eth1:
            addresses:
                - 192.168.22.2/24
            gateway4: 192.168.22.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.22.1]
```